# Handling Timeouts in a Socket Server

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets

I have an asynchronous socket server that contains a thread-safe collection of all connected clients.  If there's no activity coming from a client for a set amount of time (i.e. timeout), the server application should disconnect the client.  Can someone suggest the best way to efficiently track this timeout for each connected client and disconnect when the client times out?  This socket server must be very high performance and at any given time, hundreds of client could be connected.

One solution is to have each client associated with a last activity timestamp and have a timer periodically poll the collection to see which connection has timed out based on that timestamp and disconnect it.  However, this solution to me isn't very good because that would mean the timer thread has to lock the collection whenever it polls (preventing any other connections/disconnections) for the duration of this process of checking every connected client and disconnecting when timed out.

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of collection, exactly?  That can make a big difference.

Comment: i'm currently just using a concurrent dictionary, with the key being some generated unique numeric ID for each client connection.  i'm totally open to suggestions on replacing this collection with anything that can provide a better solution to my problem.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a new project or if you're open to a major refactor of your project, have a look at Reactive Extensions. Rx has an elegant solution for timeouts in asynchronous calls:

```
var getBytes = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(_readStream.BeginRead, _readStream.EndRead);

getBytes(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
     .Timeout(timeout);
```

Note, the code above is just intended to demonstrate how to timeout in Rx and it would be more complex in a real project.

Performance-wise, I couldn't say unless you profile your specific use case. But I have seen a talk where they used Rx in a complex data-driven platform (probably like your requirements) and they said that their software was able to make decisions within less than 30ms.

Code-wise, I find that using Rx makes my code look more elegant and less verbose.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i won't have enough time to do the amount of refactoring required to use reactive extensions.

Comment: How about using a `System.Threading.Timer` _per client_? You don't have to lock out other clients when handling the timeout. Also you won't have to worry about creating multiple instances of `Timer` since internally, all `Timers` use only 1 thread to keep track of timeouts and then the callbacks are run from the thread pool. So essentially, `Timer` does what you're trying to do with your collection. See this snippet of CLR via C#: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780735640467/compute-bound-asynchronous-operations/748

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!  i didn't know that all instances of System.Threading.Timer run using only one thread - that's good to know.  but because there may be a potentially large number of connections, i'm a little unsure about creating a new timer instance for each one.  i think i want better control of when the timeout code executes (i.e. the callback) rather than just having them execute on the thread pool, which would avoid any type of thread exhaustion scenarios.

Comment: If you want your callbacks to run in one thread only, you can use `System.Timers.Timer`. This class uses `System.Threading.Timer` internally but gives you an option of specifying an `ISynchronizeInvoke` object during construction. Then have that invoke your callbacks in a thread you specify.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is quite OK for many cases when the number of connected clients is small compared to the performance of the enumerating the collection of their contexts.  If you allow some wiggle room in the timeout (i.e. it's OK to disconnect the client somewhere between 55 and 65 seconds of inactivity), I'd just run the purging routine every so often.

The other approach which worked great for me was using a queue of activity tokens.  Lets use C#:

```
class token {
    ClientContext theClient; // this is the client we've observed activity on
    DateTime  theTime;       // this is the time of observed activity
};

class ClientContext {
    // ... what you need to know about the client
    DateTime lastActivity;   // the time the last activity happened on this client
}
```

Every time an activity happens on a particular client, a token is generated and pushed into FIFO queue and `lastActivity` is updated in the `ClientContext`.

There is another thread which runs the following loop:

- extracts the oldest token from the FIFO queue;
- checks if `theTime` in this token matches the `theClient.lastActivity`;
- if it does, shuts down the client;
- looks at the next oldest token in the queue, calculates how much time is left till it needs to be shutdown;
- `Thread.Sleep(<this time>)`;
- repeat

The price of this approach is a little, but constant, i.e. O(1) overhead.  One can come up with faster best case solutions, but it seems to me that it's hard to come up with a one with faster worst case performance.

Comment: wouldn't there still be a lock on that FIFO queue each time i updated it or whenever i loop it?  updating the last activity of each client is not a problem - my client connection wrapper automatically does that whenever there is activity.  the problem is when i loop this FIFO queue (or any collection for that matter), i need to lock it while processing it.  or maybe i'm just misunderstanding something here...

Comment: @shyneman: locking a queue with multiple writers and one reader is a very simple proposition.  Even if you lock the whole queue (there are better solutions, but lets assume the worst: locking the whole queue), pushing and pulling items into/from the queue is a very cheap operation.  You don't need to enumerate the queue: just push and pull.  But in reality this is one of the classic uses of lock-free queues: there are plenty of implementations on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to control timeout form within the connection thread. So you may have something like this:

```
// accept socket and open stream
stream.ReadTimeout = 10000; // 10 seconds

while (true)
{
    int bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, length)
    // process the data
}
```

The `stream.Read()` call will either return data (which means client is alive) or throw IO exception (abnormal disconnect) or return 0 (client closed the socket).

Comment: i'm using asynchronous receives and there doesn't appear to be a way to set a timeout for that.  if you know how, please let me know.

Comment: you mean you using BeginRead/EndRead ?

Comment: i'm using socket.beginreceive socket.endreceive.